# PHP - Grabbing the file extension of a path

Tags: php

Does this grab the file extension of the path? It forms part of a file upload script which goes on to check that $end is "jpg" and not something else. Could that be bypassed given what I have below?

```
$temp = strlen($path);
$end = $path[$temp-3] . $path[$temp-2] . $path[$temp-1];
```

Comment: It gives you the last three characters of the name, but if, for example, the name isn't three characters long, it probably won't do good things. So at least check that $temp > 3 (you probably want more than 3, right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

> mixed pathinfo ( string $path [, int $options = PATHINFO_DIRNAME | PATHINFO_BASENAME | PATHINFO_EXTENSION | PATHINFO_FILENAME ] )

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";    # returns: /www/htdocs/inc
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";   # returns: lib.inc.php
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";  # returns: php
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";   # returns: lib.inc  | since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

Or you could set the flag to get only the extension, like so:

```
$extension = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $extension; # prints `php` to the screen.
```

Comment: I am unable to change the code, but I want to make sure it is secure.

Comment: Well, to give an answer to that: It is not. An extension is just for program compatibility, so your computer will know how to handle it. It's not 100% secure. You can NOT rely on the fact that is an image if it says `jpg` on the end of the file.

Comment: This article gives some nice example which could actually happen. http://www.rafayhackingarticles.net/2012/01/how-websites-get-hacked-with-fileupload.html

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make sure that a valid image was uploaded, don't rely on the file ending, which can be tampered with. You may use the PHP image functions to make sure, that a file really is an image, e.g.:

```
function is_image($path) {
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the info but I am assessing the existing code as I can't change it

Comment: For checking the file extension, your code is Safe. It doesn't make sure, as written above, that the file really is an image, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$ext = pathinfo('abc.jpeg' ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: I am unable to change the code, but I want to make sure it is secure

Comment: it will work perfectly. Some code will search for last 3 char (but some time we have 4 char long ext) or some will search for "." dot (some time we can have file name like "my.persocal.xls" so it having  two dots), in above all cases this will work perfectly.

Comment: so the code I posted cannot be abused to upload something which isn't a jpeg?

Comment: Why are you increasing your number of line to get that you can have easily with inbuilt functions available.